# MongoDB as sink connector not capturing data as expected - kafka?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am currently using MySQL database as source connector using this config below, I want to monitor changes to a database and send it to mongoDB,

Here's my source connector config,

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '''{
  "name": "source_mysql_connector",  
  "config": {  
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",  
    "database.hostname": "host.docker.internal",  
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "test",
    "database.password": "$apr1$o7RbW.GvrPIY1",
    "database.server.id": "8111999",  
    "database.server.name": "db_source",  
    "database.include.list": "example",  
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "broker:29092",  
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.example",
    "database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval":"true",
    "include.schema.changes": "true"
  }
}'''
```

Here's my sink connector (mongodb) config,

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '''{
  "name": "sink_mongodb_connector",  
  "config": {  
      "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
      "tasks.max":"1",
      "topics":"db_source.example.employees",
      "connection.uri":"mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/example?w=1&journal=true",
      "database":"example",
      "collection":"employees",
      "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081"
  }
}'''
```

Using this I was able to establish the connection and catch the data changes and store them onto mongodb collection for a table called employees,

But the problem here is when I checked the collections in mongodb the documents were saved like this,

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("60d0e6939e00e22f274ccac1"), "before" : null, "after" : { "id" : NumberLong(11), "name" : "Steve Shining", "team" : "DevOps", "birthday" : 11477 }, "source" : { "version" : "1.5.0.Final", "connector" : "mysql", "name" : "db_source", "ts_ms" : NumberLong("1624303251000"), "snapshot" : "false", "db" : "example", "sequence" : null, "table" : "employees", "server_id" : NumberLong(6030811), "gtid" : null, "file" : "mysql-bin.000003", "pos" : NumberLong(5445), "row" : 2, "thread" : null, "query" : null }, "op" : "c", "ts_ms" : NumberLong("1624303251190"), "transaction" : null }`

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("60d0e6939e00e22f274ccac2"), "before" : null, "after" : { "id" : NumberLong(12), "name" : "John", "team" : "Support", "birthday" : 6270 }, "source" : { "version" : "1.5.0.Final", "connector" : "mysql", "name" : "db_source", "ts_ms" : NumberLong("1624303251000"), "snapshot" : "false", "db" : "example", "sequence" : null, "table" : "employees", "server_id" : NumberLong(6030811), "gtid" : null, "file" : "mysql-bin.000003", "pos" : NumberLong(5445), "row" : 3, "thread" : null, "query" : null }, "op" : "c", "ts_ms" : NumberLong("1624303251190"), "transaction" : null }`

But my mysql database looks like this,

```
mysql> select * from employees;
+----+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| id   | name                | team          |  birthday   |
+----+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|  1    | Peter Smith     | DevOps     | 2003-07-21  |
| 11    | Steve Shining | DevOps     | 2001-06-04 |
| 12   | John                  | Support    | 1987-03-03  |
+----+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

I want my collections to look like this,

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("60d0e6939e00e22f274ccac2"),  "name" : "John", "team" : "Support", "birthday" :  "1987-03-03 "}`

What am I doing wrong here? Even the delete message is stored in collection like this, it is not able to identify the message and all. How do I fix it? Even the dates are not stored properly?

Updated:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '''{
  "name": "sink_mongodb_connector",  
  "config": {  
      "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
      "tasks.max":"1",
      "topics":"db_source.example.employees",
      "connection.uri":"mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/example?w=1&journal=true",
      "database":"example",
      "collection":"employees",
      "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
      "transforms": "unwrap",
      "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
      "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
      "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite"
  }
}'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not related to Mongo, but the default Debezium format.

What you see is the before, after, and additional CDC event metadata.

> not able to identify the message

It **is**, though ... `"after" : { "id" : NumberLong(12), "name" : "John", "team" : "Support", "birthday" : 6270 }`

You need to extract/flatten the event so that you **only** get the "after" field

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/event-flattening.html

---

Regarding the birthday / date values, seems to be a separate issue

Comment: So, if I get only the after field, will it work even for delete command on source? So should I flatten it at the source config or sink config?

Comment: The after event for a row deletion will be `null`. You need a secondary transform to drop null events.

Comment: Where you do the transform depends on how much data you want in the topic

Comment: "Where you do the transform depends on how much data you want in the topic", can you explain this a bit more, a topic contains all messages related to the source mysql right, that is write, update, delete etc., I want to track all messages and update them onto mongodb. Sorry I am bit new still trying to learn kafka.

Comment: In other words, do you want all the data you currently have? (id, before, after, table info, etc), or **only** the after field in the topic? You might _want_ the other information for _other consumers_, so it might make sense to only flatten the data for the sink. Otherwise, do it at the source

Comment: Can you check the question last , I have added the updated sink config, but now it's not creating the database or collection? Is it because in the docs it mentioned `ExtractNewRecordState` is only for sql database connector, so adding it to sink mongodb resulted it not creating any collection or database?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't actually use Debezium or the Mongo connectors

Comment: I know if you are running things in Docker, you shouldn't be using IP addresses anywhere unless you are connecting to a fully external server, which `172.17.x.x` addresses are not

Comment: Actually, i have mongodb setup on my host machine where as kafka, kafka connect rest of all are docker containers, the only way I could access mongodb inside container from my host was to use that `ip`, it was your comment on another question of mine lead to this. `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway`, i tried using `host.docker.internal` to access mongodb but it was not working only that IP worked. Then I found that `IP is equal to host.docker.internal`

Comment: Thank you for the information, When I add the flatten to source config, its working as expected now. Only issue is the date is not being parsed properly